# Красивый DataPicker

Tags: java, android, kotlin, view

Хочу сделать DataPicker как в моем дизайне, но поиск в инете ни к чему не привел, хотел заменить на NumberPicker, но изучив его документацию, понял что так не сделаю, помогите

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А чем вас не устраивает [такой](https://github.com/ycuwq/DatePicker)?

Comment: Не совсем понятна в чем "красота" вашего заключается.

Comment: Назвал красивый datapicker просто, а так мне нужно реализовать такой а как не знаю